# firewalld entries to allow local LAN access to httpd server on QEMU Linux guest on Fedora 25 host

Tags: linux, routes, virtual-machine, firewalld

I've got a Fedora 26 QEMU guest VM with a LAMP application running on a Fedora 25 host. I can access the guest web server from both the guest and the host, but I can't access it from the other systems on my local LAN - and I'd like to be able to do that.

I've put a host static route entry in my router (LEDE) to route the F26 guest's static IPv4 address (192.168.122.186) to the F25 host. The F25 host already has a network route entry for the virbr0 v-interface (192.168.122.0/24).

It seems that the F25 host firewall is what's blocking the access because when I disable firewalld on the F25 host, it works as required.

I'd appreciate a pointer to how to wrangle firewalld in this type of configuration.

Edit 2017/12/11:

I started off with only one firewalld zone (public), but now I'm trying 2 (public and internal). The "services" (ports) shown below have always been open. http and https, in particular, are what I need to work.

I need to route the traffic from devices on my local LAN, 10.3.2.0/24, (except the F25 host, of course) through the F25 host to the F26 guest VM. As I wrote before, the routing appears to be working, except when firewalld is running on the F25 host - in which case this traffic is blocked.

I've spent a lot of time searching, and there are two recurring topics, forwarding and masquerading. None of the things suggested has done what I require, however.

How can I do this? Tx

```
========== running: firewall-cmd --get-zones ===========
FedoraServer FedoraWorkstation block dmz drop external home internal public trusted work
========== running: firewall-cmd --get-active-zones ===========
internal
  interfaces: virbr0
public
  interfaces: enp0s31f6
========== running: firewall-cmd --get-default-zone ===========
public
========== running: firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all ===========
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s31f6
  sources:
  services: mdns ssh dhcpv6-client http https
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

========== running: firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all ===========
internal (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources:
  services: ssh http https dhcpv6-client mdns
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

$ ifconfig -a # on the F25 host
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.3.2.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.3.2.255
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 145  bytes 16680 (16.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 217  bytes 27947 (27.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7000000-f7020000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 24  bytes 2056 (2.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 2056 (2.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:93:ae:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 99  bytes 11189 (10.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 73  bytes 9612 (9.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:93:ae:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe7c:437c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:7c:43:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 99  bytes 12575 (12.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 195  bytes 17988 (17.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s31f6
10.3.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s31f6
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

Comment: Why don't you enable the port on the firewall?

Comment: I edited my post to add more info. The http and https ports were always open. Tx.